# Declaring immutable variable in try catch block, that is accessible outside the block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, immutability

I have a simple try catch block that attempts to authorise a user and sets the usedId to the relevant attribute from the decoded token, as follows:

```
let userId;
try {
    const decodedIdToken = await validateIdToken(request);
    userId = decodedIdToken.user_id;
} catch (error) {
    response.status(403).send(error);
    return;
}

const question = {
        author: userId,
        text: request.body.text,
        tags: request.body.tags,
    }
```

While this works, the mutability of the userId variable bothers me as it might be possible to attempt to use it elsewhere and find it's undefined since we haven't given it any value when initially declared. If I don't declare it outside the try block using let, i.e. I declare it inside the block using const and thus making it immutable, it's scoped to the try block and can't be used elsewhere.

One option is to use var inside the try block to hoist it, but again this is mutable and hoisting comes with its own potential pitfalls, so I prefer not to use it.

Is there a generally accepted patter for declaring variables like this, where the call that sets the value might fail (necessitating the try catch block)?

Comment: There is no solution to this issue other than declaring it outside the block with `let` to expand its scope (I would not use `var` personally).  It is a common issue, but has no pretty solution.

Comment: Sometimes, you can put all the code that wants to use the variable inside the `try {}` block, so there's nothing after the whole `try/catch` block that wants to use the variable.

Comment: Can you please post the code of the whole function, especially where you want to use the `userId` variable and what else you are doing in that `catch` block.

Comment: The other way to solve this is to have the part of the try/catch in its own function, which returns a value that is stored as `const` (or throws)

Comment: @Joe - Although, that probably doesn't change the fact that you'd still have to use `try/catch` around that function call and would likely still have the same issue unless more of the code that uses the variable can be moved into the function.

Comment: I've added some additional code to show where the userId variable is used - that's a relatively truncated portion of the `question` object and a lot of the other attributes are derived from other places, moving everything into the `try` block would effecitvely move most of the rest of my function up there to avoid the same issue with other variables.

Comment: @Harry- And, what's wrong with moving everything inside the `try` block?  That will just catch more possible exceptions.

Comment: @jfriend00 the rationale for not putting everything inside the try block is simplicity, as if everything goes inside the try block then I'll need conditional logic to work out what caused the error, whereas currently the only thing that can fail in that try block is authentication, hence it can only be a 403 error returned to the client. I may need to go down this route and use custom errors to handle, but that was my thinking originally.

Comment: @Harry - If you show us the ENTIRE real code, we can offer you better solutions.  You're defending against our suggestions by bring in things that are NOT shown in your question.  Kind of hard for us to see the whole picture here.  As you seem to already understand, putting the entire code inside the `try` is a possible solution.  You can either use nested `try/catch` or check which type of error it is in the single catch to tell what type of error.  I'd say that the latter is probably the preferred option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code that wants to use the variable so it's hard to make a specific recommendation for this particular code, but this is a common issue in Javascript and there is no pretty solution.  Depending upon the code specifics, you can sometimes move the other code that wants to use the variable to be inside the `try` block so its in scope.

If that's not feasible, then you have to do as you already know which is declare the variable before the block with `let` or declare it within the block with `var`.  I personally would avoid `var`.

You could also factor the code out into an function (with some of the other code that wants to use the variable) that either resolves with your value or rejects, but that may just leave you with the same issue (depending upon the rest of the code).

P.S. Wouldn't your `catch` block normally have a `return` in it so you don't continue execution after the `try/catch`?  If you show us the whole request handler, we can make specific recommendations.

Comment: The example code is edited for brevity, but you're right I should not have excluded the return statement in the `catch` block.